# How to "Change the Look" in My Site?

Tags: 2013, my-site, theme

I cannot find the "Change the Look" option in a My Site site. Is theming possible in a My Site Host web application?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the "Look and Feel" for My Site using the URL:

```
http://siteurl/mysitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/designgallery.aspx
```

Its the same URL as defined in "Change the look" section of Site Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but not using the SharePoint default features, you have to use a theme that include specific master pages for those sites.

I don't know what is the version that you are referring to but I'm attaching two examples from 2010 and 2013.

[image]
[image]