# Change the look and feel in OneDrive mysite

Tags: 2016, mysite, onedrive

Mysite and OneDrive  shows the default theme, we need to change the color and the background

It looks ease of cake, I went to site setting, the change the look is not available, I clicked on the right gear icon it is not listed too!!

I checked this post [How to "Change the Look" in My Site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/how-to-change-the-look-in-my-site)

It helped me to change the look for mysite but for OneDrive it still shows the old theme?

What I am missing? Do I need to enable a feature ? Or there a configuration issue?

Comment: Hello @fabio It would be great to use the search box in SE to search your question before posting a new duplicating one, maybe the question is already asked and has the right answers! Thanks!

Comment: Also please, don't foegt to upvote the helpful answers at the main question if it helped you, in case, you are sure that your question is not dublicated, please modify your question and specifiy your issue in details!

Comment: Thank you @mohamed, I am sorry for that fault, actually I followed the same steps in the main question but for OneDrive it's not changed!

Comment: No issue @fabio, just please edit your question with your new thoughts and I will open it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported to alter the look nor feel of modern OneDrive sites, which is what you should be using in 2016+.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/customize-onedrive-for-business-sites

> This applies to only the classic OneDrive for Business experience in SharePoint Online. If you are using the new default experience, this is not supported.

Comment: Thanks, is there a modern experience in SharePoint 2016? If yes how switch to classic in OneDrive!!

Comment: Why would you do that? The modern version is the only version going forward in 2019 or SharePoint Online. Once you upgrade, which eventually you will, you won't be able to implement any custom look nor feel.

Comment: Thanks Trevor , unfortunately it's company requirements

Answer (score 1):

> is there a modern experience in SharePoint 2016?

Yes, starting with the "November 2016 public update for SharePoint Server 2016 (Feature Pack 1)".

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2017/02/15/sharepoint-2016-modern-onedrive-user-experience-results-in-blank-page/

There is a sample PowerShell script in that article to switch between the default displays.